# Getting rid of a specific character in string in Pandas' column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am working with a big dataset (more than 2 million rows x 10 columns) that has a price column. The values are formatted including a thousand-dot-separator (e.g. 1.000) and also uses dots to separate decimals (e.g 3.000.75 instead of 3000,75).

I want to format the column as float but those 2 dots in a value are giving me headaches.

Typically, and assuming that there is no number over 1.000.000 for simplicity, I would do something like this

```
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    cell=str(df.iloc[i]['price'])
    if cell.count(".")==2:
        cell=cell.split(".")[0] + cell.split(".")[1] + '.' + cell.split(".")[2]
```

And then yes, format the column as float.

But I know this is far from optimal (the `for` loop).

How can I use the power of pandas to avoid the `for` here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df.price.str.replace(r'(\.)([0-9]{1,2})$', ',\\2')
```

Maybe you will have to play with the regex part, but this function is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As minho suggested, remove them with a regular expression. An easy way to code and read is to use `\D` which means all non-digits characters:

```
regex = r'\D'
df.price = df.price.str.replace(regex, '').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is a doubt on the dot that when to remove the dot and when the dot should be considered as a decimal point. My solution to this problem is to remove all dots then come s after a thousand and leave the decimal point as it is. FOllowing code may help you.

```
cell = df['price']
cell = cell.astype('str')

def func(val):
    ret = ''
    for i in range(len(val)):
        if val[i] != '.' or i%4 != 0:
            ret += val[i]       

    return ret

output = pd.Series(map(func,cell))

output = output.astype('float')
print(output)
```

You can write me if you are facing any other problem.